# Trying to create a new list of Odd numbers from a user inputted list?

Tags: list, if-statement

This is my code. I have looked at many similar codes and have mine set up exactly how I should. I do not receive an error!

The problem is the output I receive is [11]. When the user inputs [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11]. Why is it only pulling one odd number??

```
totlist = []
max_int = 10
oddlist = []
while len(totlist) < max_int:
    nums = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    totlist.append(nums)
def find_odds(totlist, oddlist):
    if len(totlist) == 0:
        return
    v = totlist.pop()
    if v % 2 == 1:
        oddlist.append(v)
find_odds(totlist,oddlist)
print(oddlist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgoot the loop boucle inside the function

```
def find_odds(totlist, oddlist):
    for item in range(len(totlist)) : # here 
        if len(totlist) == 0:
            return
        v = totlist.pop()
        if v % 2 == 1:
            oddlist.append(v)
```